# What is causing my Undefined control sequence?

Tags: errors

```
Automata1.tex
8
Undefined control sequence.
<recently read> \c@lor@to@ps 

l.8 \begin{VCPicture}{(0,0)(12,10)}
```

My Code:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{vaucanson-g}
\begin{document}


\ShowGrid
\ShowFrame
\begin{VCPicture}{(0,0)(12,10)}
%4 states
\FinalStateVar[a]{(1.15,6.125)}{Q2} \FinalState[b]{(3.5,6.1)}{Q3} \FinalStateVar[c]{(5.55,6.025)}{Q4}
\State[d]{(7.725,6)}{Q5}
%0 initial-final
%7 transitions
\LoopN{Q2}{1} \LArcL{Q3}{Q2}{1}
\ArcL{Q2}{Q3}{0} \VArcL{}{Q3}{Q4}{0}
\VArcL{arcangle=55,ncurv=1.2}{Q4}{Q2}{1} \ArcL{Q4}{Q5}{0}
\CLoopNE{Q5}{0,1}


\end{VCPicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have used pdflatex instead of latex, most likely the package you are using is based on pstricks.

Comment: How do I use latex instead?  I'm really new at Latex

Comment: @Morgan I normally use the commandline so just just type `latex` instead of `pdflatex` if you are using an editor menu then you need to look at its configuration to see which commands it runs